# Why is my DEM raster (.tif) not converting to TIN (Gives "Error 999999" instead)

Tags: convert, error-999999, tin

I am working with a DEM raster file (.tif) which I am trying to convert into a TIN. However it won't let me do this and instead I get the following "ERROR 999999: Something unexpected caused the tool to fail. Please refer to the error help for potential solutions, or contact ESRI technological support".

I checked out the error description before but I got lost. What can I do in this case? The file I work with is an 0.5m * 0.5m raster of the area its measured heigh. Furthermore, the file is a bit under 500mb.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include the text of the error message; the screenprint is difficult to read, and also this will help others who are searching for this error in the future.

Comment: Please post code and error messages as text in the body of the question. This makes the content legible on all platforms, searchable by other users, and provides those who would help the ability to cut/paste the command into their own environment without painful retyping.  As a new-ish user, please take the [Tour].

Comment: Edited the body and question

Comment: Did you try the steps mentioned at [esri help site](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/999001-999999/tool-errors-and-warnings-999998-999999-999999.htm)?

Comment: I tried to use the steps. The repair geometry does not work on the raster, it does not contain nonalphanumeric characters, I checked the location (its a special work folder), the size may be an issue, I need to store the TIN which does not go in the geodatabase, the pathway is not super long (3 subfolders, not sure if running as an admin will do anything. It's a raster without attributes to it

Comment: I believe its a size issue, given you have a raster of 500 MB. Have you tried raster to point and then create tin from those points? Also to be sure its a size issue, just try same operation on a smaller area. Also, you can try adding a larger number in the maximum number of point - hundreds of millions category. Other issue in PRO could be the lack of memory, so an hardware issue. A link to your data wont harm, so that anyone could try and replicate your issue.Try all this, get back and we'll figure this out.